# Ionic/Cordova Plugins not included in Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a Ionic v1 project and I have an issue when building on ios. Almost all of my cordova plugins are not added in the Xcode project in the left column under the folder plugin.
Cordova version : 6.2.0
Xcode version : 8.3.3

I have done :

```
cordova platforms rm ios
cordova platforms add ios
cordova build ios
```

It compiles fine but the plugin files are not added in my Xcode project (when I run the app, I have a lot of XXXPlugin class CDVXXXX (pluginName: XXX) does not exist).

- The plugin files are added in the platforms/ios/MyProject/Plugins (I can see the different folders and the files .h et .m).
- But when I open the Xcode project, there are only the files of one of my plugins (Branch.io), all the others are not here (cordova-plugin-camera, cordova-plugin-geolocation, cordova-plugin-inappbrowser, etc.)
- In my config.xml, seems ok (example : `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="~2.4.3" />`)
- In platforms/ios/MyProject/config.xml, seems ok as well (example :  `<feature name="Geolocation"><param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" /></feature>`)

I could add them manually but it takes time and every time I remove and re-add platform, I would have to do it again.

I don't know what to do, any ideas of what I'm doing wrong ? Why is XCode stopping importing plugin files after the first one (BranchSDK which appears to be the first one in alphabetical order by the way) ?

My package.json :

```
{
   "name": "myapp",
   "version": "1.1.1",
   "description": "myapp: An Ionic project",
   "dependencies": {
       "grunt-contrib-compress": "^1.3.0",
       "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^2.0.0",
       "gulp": "^3.5.6",
       "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
       "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
       "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
       "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
       "ionic-native-transitions": "^1.0.2",
       "moment": "^2.14.1",
       "ng2-translate": "^2.2.2",
       "plist": "^2.0.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
       "angular-translate": "^2.15.2",
       "bower": "^1.3.3",
       "coffee-script": "^1.10.0",
       "grunt-contrib-compress": "^1.3.0",
       "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^2.0.0",
       "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^2.0.0",
       "gulp-ng-annotate": "^2.0.0",
       "gulp-useref": "^3.1.2",
       "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
       "mv": "^2.1.1",
       "shelljs": "^0.3.0"
    },
    "cordovaPlugins": [
       "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
       "cordova-plugin-console",
       "cordova-plugin-device",
       "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
       "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
       "cordova-plugin-network-information",
       "cordova-plugin-geolocation",
       "cordova-plugin-badge"
    ],
    "cordovaPlatforms": [
       "android",
       {
         "platform": "ios",
         "version": "4.1.1",
         "locator": "ios@4.1.1"
       }
     ]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Ok..deleting my answer since it isn't correct

Comment: Pls share your package.json file contents

Comment: I updated my post with package.json. Right now I added all of my plugin files (.h, .m and .framework) one by one into the Xcode Project on the left (in the folder explorer) mais but it is very painful. And if a remove ios platform and re-add it, I will have to do it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cordova version : 6.2.0

cordova@6.2.0 [was released](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2016/05/24/tools-release.html) over 1½ years ago. Try updating to the latest version `cordova@7.1.0`

Then install the latest iOS platform: `cordova platform add ios@latest`

> Xcode version : 8.3.3

While you're at it, update to Xcode 9 so you can build for iOS 11 / iPhone X.

Comment: I will update cordova  but right now, I need to upload an app update with the current version. And before it worked fine and I don't know what triggered the issue

Answer (score 1):

delete plugins folder, node_module folder and platform/ios folder. Then run "npm install in the project root. The add ios platform